# Reading a mipmap resource for a specific density

Tags: android

How can I read bytes from a specific mipmap image? For example, I'm trying to read bytes from **ic_launcher.png** that's located at **mipmap-xxhdpi**

[image]

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
InputStream ins = getResources().
            openRawResource(getResources().
                    getIdentifier("ic_launcher.png",
            "mipmap-xxhdpi", getPackageName()));
```

But I get an exception saying that the resource was not found. What is the right way to do it? I want to read the file in **mipmap-xxhdpi** particularly

Comment: May I ask: Why exaclty would you need to know the size of this file?

Comment: I know the size of this file... My task is to read specific bytes from this specific file (and not the other ic_launcher.png files)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20918685/how-to-get-image-from-drawable-xhdpi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can get that specific drawable for xxhdpi with

```
ResourcesCompat.getDrawableForDensity(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH, getTheme());
```

after that you could make a bitmap a compress it back to png

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
drawable.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] pngBytes = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: This helps. My min API level is 15, any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: this should be fine with api 15, maybe you are calling getDrawableForDensity(int, int, Resources.Theme), that requires api 21

Comment: To support API 15, use `ResourcesCompat.getDrawableForDensity(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher, 480, getTheme());` . According to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_XXHIGH , `DENSITY_XXHIGH` is a constant value 480.

Comment: For some reason `DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH` requires API level 16.. I will stay with 480. Thanks again!