# Bitmap decoding returning null

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

```
final Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

I am getting a null references error.

> B is null.

Why is that?

Comment: you are getting null in activity or fragment.

Comment: activity is where I'm getting a null.

Comment: please check import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory; in your activity

Comment: I already have that.

Comment: could you post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

Good question i went in the exact same issue (with the exact same file :)
It seems that
BitmapFactory.decodeResource works quite perfect with R.drawable and R.raw but not with mipmaps probably caused by the different screen resolutions, but this is just a guess.
Looking in the source i can only see that decodeResource calls Resource#openRawResource(..) and the documentation says:

> ... asset file -- that is, it can be used to open drawable, sound, and
> raw resources;it will fail on string and color resources.

i guess mipmap files are not considered as raw resources as there is additional handling for choosing density dependent resources.
So you will have to specify the density of the resource: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41910618/8524651

Or quick and dirty just move a copy of that file to your raw folder.

The solution code in kotlin (decide for one way ;)

```
        val launcherDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawableForDensity(context.resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW, context.getTheme());
        var bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.raw.ic_launcher)
        bm = launcherDrawable!!.toBitmap(launcherDrawable.minimumWidth, launcherDrawable.minimumHeight)
```

Answer (score -1):

This may help you

```
 Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.imagefile);
 Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
```